# Updating a date record in a table using VBA & cmd button

Tags: ms-access, button, command, vba

I'm trying to get a Command Button to update a date on a table.  The button is in a separate form.  Right now I'm trying:

```
Private Sub Command13_Click()

 Update Master
     Set [Last Complete] = Date()
End Sub
```

"Master" being the table I'm trying to update and "Last Complete" being the specific record.

Access throws an error message with my code, complaining *"sub or function isn't properly defined"*.

I've worked quite a bit with VBA in Excel but not so much with Access.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I'm getting the error that the "sub or function isn't properly defined".

Comment: Is the record the same one that the currnet form is bound to? If yes, then simply go me.Last_Complete = date(). You don’t see a set command or any sql.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a SQL statement is not valid VBA code.

You can place the statement in a string and use the `DAO.Database.Execute` method to execute it:

```vb
Private Sub Command13_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "Update Master Set [Last Complete] = Date()"
End Sub
```

Assuming that `UPDATE` statement is valid and does what you want, that could be all you need.  However, here is another version which demonstrates features you may find useful:

```vb
Private Sub Command13_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strUpdate As String
    strUpdate = "Update Master Set [Last Complete] = Date()"
    Debug.Print strUpdate
    Set db = CurrentDb
    db.Execute strUpdate, dbFailOnError
    Debug.Print db.RecordsAffected & " rows updated"
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  That got me further along than I have been.  The only issue now is that it updates every record in [Last Complete] as opposed to the one selected.  Is that the "Set" argument?

Comment: No, you need to add a `WHERE` clause to limit the scope of the `UPDATE`.  The `WHERE` condition should identify the target row(s).  I suggest you create a `SELECT` query in the Access query designer.  Work out your `WHERE` condition there.  Once it selects the correct row(s), add that `WHERE` clause to your `UPDATE`.